# How do you unset all variables based on a prefix in zsh?

Tags: variables, zsh, substitution, unset

In bash you can do something like this:

```
unset "${!AWS_@}"
```

But this will give a substitution error in zsh.

I haven't found a really great way to do this in zsh. Presumably because zsh has a different expansion/substitution than bash. I'm assuming I would have to do a lookup and then loop through the return. I'm wondering if someone has a nice one liner (or has ran into this themselves).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-m` flag.

```
unset -m "AWS_*"
```

From the entry for `unset` in `man zshbuiltins`:

> If  the  **-m** flag is specified the arguments are taken as patterns (should be
> quoted) and all parameters with matching names are unset.   Note  that  this
> cannot  be  used when unsetting associative array elements, as the subscript
> will be treated as part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is pretty gross:

```
unset $(printenv | grep AWS_ | awk -F \= '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This also works but is more gross:

```
for i in (printenv | grep AWS_ | awk -F \= '{print $1}')
  unset $i
end
```